# What is the advantage of calling method through delegates over calling with the help of class object in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

```
using System;
namespace multicastdeligate
{
    delegate void Del1(int s);
    class TestClass
    {
        static void number(int s)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("  Hello, {0}!", s);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Del1 x, y;
            x = number;
            y = number;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Invoking delegate x:");
            x(5);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Invoking delegate y:");
            y(5);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Invoking through method call:");
            number(5);
        }
    }
}
```

I have called through normal function calling and delegates.

what is the need to call function using delegate?

Comment: Please, don't afraid to use web search before asking. There is a lot of information about what is it, and when to use it.

Comment: @Dennis.. i searched but i couldnt found..can you send me an link..

Comment: It's right below your question's title.